# Cannot load @Configuration class in component test marked as @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

I am testing a functionality and has written a componentTest to ensure the component is working. The issue is when running the test @Configuration class is not loading for the test. Example:

TestClass:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ServiceTest{

//Do Something

}
```

```
@Configuration

public class ConfigurationClass{

@PostConstruct
public void doSomething(){
log.info("Test loading");
}

}
```

When running the application, I can see the logs printed on application startup. When I run the test, I don't see the logs printing from the `ConfigurationClass`. I tried using `@ContextConfiguration(classes=ConfigurationClass.class)` but no luck.

Practically , I want the configurationClass to be loaded before the tests are loaded.

Comment: In what packages are `Application` and `ConfigurationClass` ?

Comment: Application in java/com.example.spring.context and configurationClass in java/com.example/spring.context.service.log

Answer (score 1):

When you run `@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)` with a specified `class`, its instructs the spring boot test engine to load only beans defined in `Application.java` which is supposed to (usually) be a class annotated with `@Configuration` annotation directly or indirectly.

If you want to just load the whole application context in the test, just use `@SpringBootTest` without any attributes. Now in this case it will scan packages up to one with `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotation (which presents on the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and then will scan the packages down to load the configuration classes.

Of course you should make sure that the test will be able to find `@SpringBootApplication` class, for that you should put the test in the same package or beneath (of course the tests are in `src/test/java` as opposed to the `src/main/java` where you main class resides.